# JS - String includes a substring that matches regex

Tags: javascript

Check if a JavaScript string includes a substring that matches a regex.

I have tried string.includes(substring)

```
var myString =  "This is my test string: AA.12.B.12 with some other chars";
myString.includes(/^[A-Z]{2}\.\d{2}\.\[A-Z]{1}\.\d{2,3}$/);
```

True, False

However, code doesn't compile

Comment: Make the regex and then use `.test()` with the string as the argument.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use `.test()` on your regular expression to check whether the pattern matches part of the string. As the pattern will need to match only a portion of the string, you will need to remove the `^` and `$` characters as your matched pattern can be contained within a line. Also, there is no need to escape the character class bracket as you have tried to do so in your expression (`\[`), as you want the `[` to be treated as a character class, not a literal square bracket:

```js
const myString =  "This is my test string: AA.12.B.12 with some other chars";
const res = /[A-Z]{2}\.\d{2}\.[A-Z]{1}\.\d{2,3}/.test(myString);
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 5):

If we look at the docs for [String.prototype.includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes) we can see it takes a string, not a regular expression. Instead, try [RegExp.prototype.test()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test).

Also, since you only want to match a sub-string, you'll need to remove the start and end anchors `^` and `$`. ([More on regex anchors](https://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html))

Your code becomes:

```
var myString =  "This is my test string: AA.12.B.12 with some other chars";
var myRegex = /[A-Z]{2}\.\d{2}\.\[A-Z]{1}\.\d{2,3}/;
console.log(myRegex.test(myString));
```